# How to use LINQ to get the first matching file from inside a ZipArchive?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to select a file as `ZipArchiveEntry` from within a `ZipArchive` using LINQ.

What I have so far

```
string filename = "foo";
using ( FileStream zipFile = new FileStream( Path.Combine( FilePathLocal, filename + ".zip" ), FileMode.Open ) ) {
    using ( ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive( zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Read ) ) {
        var txtInZip = archive.Entries.Select( x => x.FullName == filename + ".txt" );
        using ( Stream csvStream = txtInZip.Open() ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line I am having trouble with :

```
var txtInZip = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault( x => x.FullName == filename + ".txt" );
```

`txtInZip` is always returning null.  I also tried using `Select` in place of `FirstOrDefault`

What do I need to do to correct this LINQ query so that it returns the ZipArchiveEntry as intended ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read from the documentation you need to compare the filename to the Name property as the FullName property contains the relative path to the file.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I was reading through ZipArchiveEntry docs, and didn't see that. Also noticed there was a `(A)` in filename (from the name of the zip), but the txt file inside is identical except for that.  I adjusted my query accordingly and will also be using `.Name` from now on.  `Path.GetFileName( x.FullName )` usually works as well, but `x.Name` is less processing / headache for my needs.  Thank you for that ! (upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault will return null [for nullable objects] if no items match your test.

So for whatever reason, it looks like archive.Entries does not contain an object with a FullName equal to filename + ".txt"

To debug this:  put a breakpoint somewhere in your "using" block, attach your debugger, and when the breakpoint gets hit, hover over archive.Entries, expand the items and look at the FullNames to see why they're not what you expected.  You can also look to see if there's another property that *is* what you expected.  Remember that c# == comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: I was using the debugger to inspect variables and using break points (of course). I didn't notice but the zip file has a "(A)" where the file inside does not. Also adjusted my filter based the information Thomas supplied. (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code to read all filenames from all files inside a zip file including inner zip files recursively:

```
List<ZipArchive> Archives = new List<ZipArchive>();

void outputFileNames(string file)
{
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        var parentArchive = new ZipArchive(fileStream);
        Archives.Add(parentArchive);
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in parentArchive.Entries)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(entry.Name).Equals(".zip"))
            {
                addArchivesToList(new ZipArchive(entry.Open()));
            }
        }

        foreach (var archive in Archives)
        {
            foreach (var e in archive.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + e.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}

void addArchivesToList(ZipArchive archive)
{
    Archives.Add(archive);
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(entry.Name).Equals(".zip"))
        {
            addArchivesToList(new ZipArchive(entry.Open()));
        }
    }
}
```

You could just implement an exit condition once you find the first match inside the section:

```
foreach (var e in archive.Entries)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + e.Name);
}
```